# DJango forms : Invalid choice error when saving form input to database

Tags: python, django, forms

I do have an invalid choice error when trying to save value from my django form to my database. Here is the details :

I do have a model with multiples choices for the value

```py
class ActivityType(models.Model):
    CHOICES = (
        ('Randonnée', 'Randonnée'),
        ('Raquettes', 'Raquettes'),
        ('VTT', 'VTT'),
        ('Via ferrata', 'Via ferrata'),
}
```

Then , another model contain the previous one as foreign key :

```py
class TopoUnit (models.Model):
 
    activity_type = models.ForeignKey(ActivityType, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

I defined a form to fufill this model :

```
class TopoUnitForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)


        self.fields['activity_type'].choices = ActivityType.CHOICES
      
    class Meta:
        model = TopoUnit
        fields = '__all__'
```

On the HTML template, I'm displaying the form

```
<div class="form-group">
      <label>Activité</label>
      {{ form.activity_type }}
</div>
```

Finnaly,here is my view :

```
def returnPage(request): #Called when the form is clicked
    form = TopoUnitForm() #Instanciate the form

    if (request.method == 'POST') :
        print(request.POST) #Print in CLI
        form = TopoUnitForm(request.POST) #Some var wihch can be used in the html {{form}}
        if form.is_valid():
            print("saving")
            form.save() #save in the database
        else :
            print('\n' +  str(form.errors))

    context = {'form' : form }
    return render(request, 'guidebook.html', context)
```

Unfortunatley, when pressing the button with an option selected in the form options list, the form_is_valid() return false. I Obtain the following :

```
<QueryDict: {'csrfmiddlewaretoken': ['sleuCM0zO5ISNwOImsMoTUmkWLNe8Z2nqXAHLno6K2uF8FPe6pQSM6nANfa3W92G'], 'activity_type': ['VTT']}>

<ul class="errorlist"><li>activity_type<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. That choice is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li></ul>
[14/Jul/2023 13:12:37] "POST /guidebook/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5697
```

Why, and how to fix it ?

Comment: Share your full `ActivityType` model. You missed to use your `CHOICES` in a model field. E.g. with a charfield and choices.